# Repeat question for each locality?

Tags: discussion, localization

There is a recent example of someone repeating the same question, once for the UK and once for the US:

- [What are the pros and cons of different types of smart switches (that are on the US market) ?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-types-of-smart-switches-that-are-on-the)
- [What are the pros and cons of different types of smart switches on the UK market?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-types-of-smart-switches-that-are-on-the)

I think this is a bad idea.  I mean, once the Australians and Germans and Canadians also make their own copy of the question, the site will be a mess.  And any useful non-localized advice in the answers will not reach people from other countries.

A better solution would be to just ask the question once and let people answer according to the region they know something about (and mark they answers accordingly).  The questioner should accept the overall best answer *for him*, taking into account which answer is most helpful in his locality.  Good answers for other localities will get many votes from other users and therefore be ranked highly also.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really bad idea. It falls 100% squarely into my concerns about **[Asking the First Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)**.

Users should ask questions when they need help. Others like answering their questions to show off their knowledge and help other get better at what they do. But if there is an *appearance* that the author doesn’t really care about the answer, then there is a danger that the whole system could be regarded as a big waste of time. True, the ultimate goal is to build a repository of knowledge, but users don't want to be given a bunch of busy-work, either.