# Details: Adding prompts for age and location of home, construction details, photos

Tags: feature-request

A high fraction of DIY questions hinge on details that posters leave out: age of the home, jurisdiction (especially for electrical questions), and most of all a photo.

What's the chance stack central might be convinced to add fixed prompts for use by various stacks?  I'd want to see "age of house" asked for most questions on DIY, other stacks would configure other fixed questions.

Comment: Here's another example of a question where the location was critical to the answer: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36911/air-admittance-valves-on-waste-pipe-with-extraction/37055#37055

Answer (score 2):

You're not the first to want this (see [Should question-askers be required to state their location?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/2196)), but I'm not sure how open SE is to modifying the question section. If a question can't be answered due to a lack of details, be sure to comment about the missing details and vote to close as unclear (which [requires 3k of rep](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)) or flag it for mod attention so we can place the question on hold if you have less than 3k of rep.

Comment: It's unlikely SE would add a feature just for DIY.  But if there were a general feature to ask for metadata, set up by each stack, that might fly.

Comment: You can always ask on meta.SO to get more attention for your request, just realize that the reception there isn't always a warm one.

Comment: Yeah, this would be a major feature addition that we'd have to consider for the whole network (or as a site setting so individual sites can decide if they need it or not). Consider adding a feature request on [metase].